# How to use DELETE verb with servicestack razor MVC

Tags: razor, servicestack, http-delete

I want to use the DELETE HTTP verb with MVC razor, but can't find a way to do so. I tried having a form use

```
@foreach (var result in Model.Results)
{
  <li>
    <form action="@result.DeleteUrl" method="POST">
      <input name="X-HTTP-Method-Override" type="hidden" value="DELETE" />
      <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
    </form>)
  </li>
}

[Route("/results/{Id}", "POST,DELETE")]
  public class Result
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string DeleteUrl
    {
      get
      {
        return "/results/{0}".Fmt(Id);
      }
    }

    public Result() { }
    public Result(string id)
    {
      Id = id;
    }
  }

  public class ResultsService : Service
  {
    public object Delete(Result request)
    {
      // TODO: Never called!
      return null;
    }
  }
```

This still does not call my Delete callback on my service. I've seen that the http://razor-console.servicestack.net/rockstars example uses GET with a delete url to delete its items! POST works fine, but I want to use DELETE.

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Support for this [has now been added](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/563057a8af37cad14f9a7240683f71e0e8792181) available from v3.9.38+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked about this in the ServiceStack Google Group. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/servicestack/HY-dCjgq2Pw

It doesn't appear ServiceStack currently has support for what you are trying do to in your Form.

Comment: Support for this [has now been added](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/563057a8af37cad14f9a7240683f71e0e8792181) available from v3.9.38+